# Travis CI + Swift build error thrown on UILabel

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, travis-ci

we're currently deploying to Travis CI with our swift project. however, it throw errors on the UITablew view cell:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("categoryCell") as? UITableViewCell

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "categoryCell")
    }
    //Use custom view for the indicator
    TableCellHelper.initAccessoryView(cell!)

    cell!.textLabel?.textColor=Theme.sharedInstance.mainTextColor
    cell!.textLabel?.font=Theme.sharedInstance.mainTextFont
    cell!.textLabel?.text = viewModel?.categories[indexPath.row].title
    return cell!
}


/Users/travis/build/Source/Platform/ViewController/Category/CategoryListViewController.swift:107:24: error: operand of postfix '?' should have optional type; type is 'UILabel'
            cell!.textLabel?.textColor=Theme.mainTextColor
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^

    /Users/travis/build/Source/Platform/ViewController/Category/CategoryListViewController.swift:108:24: error: operand of postfix '?' should have optional type; type is 'UILabel'
            cell!.textLabel?.font=Theme.mainTextFont
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^

    /Users/travis/build/Source/Platform/ViewController/Category/CategoryListViewController.swift:109:24: error: operand of postfix '?' should have optional type; type is 'UILabel'
            cell!.textLabel?.text = categories[indexPath.row].title
    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
      1) Compile Swift source files
    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
    (null)
    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
    ** BUILD FAILED ** (139653 ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your Travis CI instance is running older version of Xcode.

My Xcode 6.1.1 has the following declaration of `UITableViewCell`

```
@availability(iOS, introduced=2.0)
class UITableViewCell : UIView, NSCoding, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, NSObjectProtocol {

    [...]

    @availability(iOS, introduced=3.0)
    var textLabel: UILabel? { get } // default is nil.  label will be created if necessary.

    [...]
```

Please note it is declared as optional: `UILabel?`.
The earlier versions of Xcode has this declaration like

```
var textLabel: UILabel { get }
```

not optional.

This declaration was present on first versions of Xcode 6 and this was changed with updates.

**update**

I can't find any official information regarding this update but you may go through [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html) and see related information for Xcode 6.1 updates.
Still there is no information regarding this exact field but you may see a lot of APIs was in liquid state in early releases.

Comment: thanks for that. how can i check my travis xcode version and update to 6.1.1?

Comment: @Kiddo, Where is your TravisCI instance hosted?

Comment: travis-ci.org in the cloud

Comment: sorry. @Max  it's at magnum.travis-ci.com

Comment: on their website:
http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/osx-ci-environment/
Xcode #

Xcode 6.1 is installed with the iOS 7.0, 7.1 and 8.1 simulators and SDKs. Command Line Tools are also installed.

Comment: They say it has Xcode 6.1: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/osx-ci-environment/#Xcode . You may try to download Xcode 6.1 from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20- and verify this bug on your side.

Comment: Maybe it is reasonable to ask their support regarding Xcode update.

Answer (score 0):

currently Travis-CI only supports Xcode 6.1

http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/osx-ci-environment/#Xcode

> Xcode #
>
> Xcode 6.1 is installed with the iOS 7.0, 7.1 and 8.1 simulators and
>   SDKs. Command Line Tools are also installed.

However they did make an optional update to 6.1.1

http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-environment-updates/2014-12-18/

All I need to do is:

> During the opt-in period, the updated image can be accessed by adding
>   osx_image: xcode611 to your .travis.yml.

Comment: Be aware that according to staff at Travis CI, this setting must now be enabled with a per-repository feature-flag.  See [IRC log](https://botbot.me/freenode/travis/2015-03-31/?msg=35478440&page=3) for full discussion.